# Converting varchar to varbinary SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-data

I have two different tables in my database and I am joining them to extract a varbinary or a varchar depending on which one comes first. I am using the operator `coalesce` to select between them and also using the `convert` operator to convert the varchar to varbinary.
The final query is something like this:

```
select coalesce(t1.varbinary_column, convert(varbinary(max), t2.varchar_column)) form table1 t1 inner join table2 t2....
```

The query returns a byte array that when converted to a java.lang.String separates each character with a additional space.
Is also needed to say that I am using spring data to execute this native query and also using ResultSet to get the extracted data.
The question is how can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Try using nvarchar instead of varchar. Not sure, but that has always helped me when dealing with strings and sql server.

Comment: When posting your query, make sure you copy and paste it. `form table` isn't valid syntax. Although this might seem silly, if you have simply typographical errors like that and then ask a "why isn't this working" questions you're going to be told the reason is because of the spelling mistake.

Comment: If the query is working properly in sql server (you can test with the management studio ) then the problem is your java code and you can give us some of that to see :)

Comment: I had a spelling mistake in the query.
It actually looks like:
`select coalesce(t1.content, convert(varbinary(max), t2.content))
from table1 t1 inner join table t2 on t1.id = t2.t1_id`

Comment: @Larnu Well, you called it!  :)

Comment: Wait, so the reason why this wasn't working really was because of `form table`...? **/headdesk**

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem. the query is executing. But returns a byte array that when converted to a String separates adds a space after each character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing the retrieved data I saw that Sql Server was converting automatically the varchar data to varbinary encoded with UTF-16LE. To sove it with the java code, I just nedded to instanciate a String passing the encoding like this:

```
new String(retrievedByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"))
```

Comment: how do you know SQL Server was using `UTF-16LE` ?